# How to prompt user for tags and use the result in a org-ql-search function?

Tags: org-mode, completing-read, org-ql

Is there a way to read tags *with completion* from the user in the same way `read-number` or `read-string` allows?

I would like to have a custom function defined where I ask the user for a tag (or list of tags) and use that in a `org-ql-search` query.

Comment: Tags are strings, are they not?

Comment: yes, but then you don't get the tag completion. You would have to guess/remember which tags are available.

Comment: You should put that requirement in the question.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get all the buffer tags by calling `org-get-buffer-tags`. You can then combine that with `completing-read` whose doc string reads as follows:

> completing-read is a built-in function in ‘C source code’.
>
> (completing-read PROMPT COLLECTION &optional PREDICATE REQUIRE-MATCH
>   INITIAL-INPUT HIST DEF INHERIT-INPUT-METHOD)
>
> ...
>
> Read a string in the minibuffer, with completion.
>   PROMPT is a string to prompt with; normally it ends in a colon and a space.
>   COLLECTION can be a list of strings, an alist, an obarray or a hash table.
>   COLLECTION can also be a function to do the completion itself...

So here's a function to do what you want:

```
(defun my-read-tag-with-completion ()
  (interactive)
  (completing-read "Enter a tag: " (org-get-buffer-tags)))
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks!